# Can't resolve memoization design pattern with fibonacci

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

I don't understand the last steps in the memoization design pattern. This is my code with classic fibonacci calculation:

```js
//Memoization
      const fiboCache = () => {
        const cache = [0,1];
        const fibo = (x) => {
          let result = cache[x];
          if(typeof result !== 'number') {
            console.log('new calculation for: ' + x);
            result = fibo(x-1) + fibo(x-2);
            cache[x] = result;
          }
          return result;
        };
        return fibo;
      };
      const getFibo = fiboCache();
      console.log(getFibo(4));
```

The problem for me is the last step, I tried to break it down each iteration which looks like this:

```
4. result=undef; console.log; result=3; cache=[0,1,empty,empty,3]
3. result=undef; console.log; result=2; cache=[0,1,empty,2,3]
2. result=undef; console.log; result=1; cache=[0,1,1,2,3]
1. result=1; return 1;
```

I understand how the array is working as cache for my next calculations, but as soon as I'm on the last iteration (1) my `result` object becomes 1 which is breaking my recursion, and I'm going straight to `return result`.

Doesn't that mean I'm just returning `1` at the end? Shouldn't I return here the last item of my array?

Comment: I think your iteration list is wrong: the cache will be filled in from the left hand end, on the way back up the recursion, i.e. you'll never have [0,1,empty,empty,3].

Comment: And you'll have a lower max recursion depth if you switch your result line to be `result = fibo(x-2) + fibo(x-1)` i.e. do -2 first.

Comment: could you help me with the iteration list to understand it? I was thinking when i give the function the parameter 4 it does start with cache[4] which isnt existing (so it fills empty until position 4 in the array).

Comment: @thedoomer1000 it will break recursion, yes, but again you have been putting things in the stack with each recursive call and as soon as your last return happens, things will start "popping" and you will get value at the bottom of the stack which will be the one at your desired position in the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite that simple: you'll have to work up and down the recursion levels as each one returns. It'll go something like this

- fibo(4), cache = [0,1] - not in cache; compute it from fibo(3) and fibo(2)

  - fibo(3), cache = [0,1] - not in cache; compute it from fibo(2) and fibo(1)

    - fibo(2), cache = [0,1] - not in cache; compute it from fibo(1) and fibo(0)

      - fibo(1), cache = [0,1] - return 1 from cache
      - fibo(0), cache = [0,1] - return 0 from cache
    - back to fibo(2): result = fibo(1) + fibo(0) = 1 + 0 = 1; write cache[2] = 1, return 1
    - fibo(1), cache = [0,1,1] - return 1 from cache
  - back to fibo(3): result = fibo(2) + fibo(1) = 1 + 1 = 2; write cache[3] = 2, return 2
  - fibo(2), cache = [0,1,1,2] - return 1 from cache
- back to fibo(4), cache = [0,1,1,2]: result = fibo(3) + fibo(2) = 2 + 1 = 3; write cache[4] =3, return 3

i.e.

- each recursion returns a value back to the level higher up, and you get the result from the top level = 3 not the first time you hit the return (1) as you'd thought
- the cache is updated after each recursion level has completed; you'll never end up with [0,1,empty,empty,3] as you originally had.

It may also be instructive to step through this with a debugger and watch the cache contents and the call stack.

Comment: Do you know why i got downvoted? What did I wrong, what could i make better next time?

Comment: Wasn't me sorry (nor the 'needs more focus' close vote - which I don't understand either). I'd guess someone thought this was something you could figure out for yourself - I don't know